# StringIO instance mutating original string

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I have observed some very odd behaviour using Ruby's StringIO class.

Type the following in an irb console:

```
2.3.0 :002 > original_string = 'test'
 => "test" 
2.3.0 :003 > original_string.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Encoding is UTF-8. Now construct a new StringIO instance

```
2.3.0 :004 > io = StringIO.new(original_string)
 => #<StringIO:0x007fe0ad08e4f0> 
2.3.0 :005 > original_string.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

`original_string` is still UTF-8, now set encoding on derived StringIO instance

```
2.3.0 :006 > io.set_encoding('BINARY')
 => #<StringIO:0x007fe0ad08e4f0> 
2.3.0 :007 > original_string.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Original string encoding has been mutated to ASCII! Is this expected behaviour? Constructing the StringIO object `StringIO.new(original_string.freeze)` prevents the encoding change rather than raising an error, which I would expect if the change to `original_string`'s encoding was expected.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?  I believe `stringIO` used to be a pretty thin layer over an underlying string, but https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11827 implies that the encoding stuff might now (2.3.x and later?) be independent between the source string and the IO wrapper.

Comment: I've reproduced the above on 2.3 and 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional - if the stream is writable (in the case of `IOString` this would be if the underlying string is writable) then a `set_encoding` on the stream also sets the encoding on the underlying string.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/stringio/stringio.c#L1602